# LibreOffice: Unsupported URL <private:stream>: "" With django-webodt

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, libreoffice

I am using [django-webodt](https://github.com/NetAngels/django-webodt) to create PDFs from Django with LibreOffice as the converter under Ubuntu 12.04.

I start LibreOffice in headless mode using the following command:

```
soffice '--accept=socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.NamingService' --headless
```

However, I am getting an intermittent error from LibreOffice:

```
com.sun.star.lang.IllegalArgumentException at /report/2013/09/Unsupported URL <private:stream>: ""
```

I have installed the latest version of LibreOffice using `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`. The issue is intermittent in that yesterday it was working, today it I am getting this error! Nothing has changed at all, except for a system reboot.

Can anyone help explain what the problem might be?